# Single Quotes inside Single Quotes removing Forward Slashes

Tags: php, escaping, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have this code:

```
$profile_image_url = str_replace(" ", "%20", 'https://www.example.com/images/cropped (1).jpg');

$output .= "style='background:url('https://www.example.com/images/" . $profile_image_url . "')no-repeat;'";
```

The output results in:

```
style="background:url(" https: www.example.com images cropped (1).jpg')no-repeat;
```

How can I fix this line of code to prevent the URL slashes from being removed? Thank you!

```
$output .= "style='background:url('https://www.example.com/images/" . $profile_image_url . "')no-repeat;'";
```

I've tried escaping the innermost single quotes with a backslash but it did not work -->

```
$output .= "style='background:url(\'https://www.example.com/images/" . $profile_image_url . "\')no-repeat;'";
```

Comment: _"the output results in"_ - what is the code in between? How do you echo/vardump `$output`? And you would have a single-quote problem in js anyway: `style='background:url('https..` the second `'` would need to be escaped. But it all depends on how you output it to where.

Comment: its echoed at the end "echo $output;"

Comment: there must be something in between, because also the single quote here `style='back` changes to a double quote. See this fiddle: https://3v4l.org/b9e4C The code you are showing here is working as you'd expect.

Comment: Just the 2 lines at the top of your question produce the correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really removing the slashes. You'll see them if you view the page source rather than using inspect.

Put the style attribute value in double quotes.

```
$output .= "style=\"background:url('https://www.example.com/images/" . $profile_image_url . "')no-repeat;\"";
```

Or put the URL in double quotes.

```
$output .= "style='background:url(\"https://www.example.com/images/" . $profile_image_url . "\")no-repeat;'";
```

Unescaped single quotes inside single quotes is not possible. The second single quote encountered will close the first one. And escaping them doesn't work in that context, as you've seen.